# Conversion Failed error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a problem in my code and I figure it out:

```
SELECT
   pono,
   convert(varchar,podate,103) as podate,
   Convert(varchar,validity,103) as validity,
   OriginalPOno, Sitename, Vendorname 
FROM  dbo.tbl_POR_PO_MAIN 
WHERE originalpono not in (select originalpono from tbl_Despatch_POR_PO_Main)
  AND pono not in (select pono from tbl_Despatch_POR_PO_Main)
  AND status=15
  AND (DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),validity)<=1)
ORDER BY sitename, validity, originalpono
```

This gives me a following error:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Which database engine is this?

Comment: Can you show us the table structure?? What datatypes are the `podate` and `validity` columns? Also: when converting, I would **always** define a **length** for the resulting string! Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ....)` instead of using just `varchar` without any length

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/2e36331d-0081-47e4-a0f4-fe3183547187/):

> SQL Server expects dates in the format mm/dd/yyyy so you will need to
> convert your date into this format before submitting.
>
> The problem with this error is that if the day value of a date is
> <=12, it will automagically be converted to mm/dd/yyyy giving you the
> false impression that your code is working.  it's not until the day
> hits 13> that the problem raises it's ugly head.

Sounds like this could be the issue,maby you should take a looka the podate structure.

Answer (score 0):

Please check data in column podate and validity. Any of this column is having string value. That is the reason why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MSSQL server ISDATE() function it returns 0 if a string isn't date and 1 if it is date and can be converted. Try to run following select and check incorrect strings:

```
select 'incorrect podate',  podate from dbo.tbl_POR_PO_MAIN where ISDATE(podate)=0
union all
select 'incorrect validity',  validity from dbo.tbl_POR_PO_MAIN where ISDATE(validity)=0
```